# Can a workflow created in Sharepoint Designer be imported into Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Is it possible to create a workflow in SharePoint designer and then import it into a SharePoint site? Does the workflow need to be a resusable workflow?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Wht do you need it to do?  List level workflows aren't portable; site level workflows aren't much better.  Reusuable workflows are designed with portability in mind.  They can be attached to content types on lists / libraries too under thier respective workflow configuration screens.

If you can give us a little more information on what you're after that'd be great.

Comment: I'm working on a SharePoint that has been locked down so we can't use Sharepoint designer. I can use it on my 'own' SharePoint site. So I was wondering if I can use SP Designer to create a workflow on my 'own' site, if I set up a matching list to the one on the main site. Then once the workflow has been designed, import it into the SharePoint main site.

Comment: Do you have the ability to upload list templates within your production environment?

Comment: Probably not, it's very locked down. What are list templates anyway.

Comment: Whenever you create a list, you create it from a template.  SharePoint has plenty of these OOB but you can create your own.  I'ver seen some workflows moved across sites using list templates and was thinking this may have been a solution to your question.

Comment: Cool, I will look into the list templates we have available.